# Ruuning conftest before distribution using pytest xdist

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

Can any one help with a solution for the following requirement. I have to connect to a VM before starting test suite only once for the entire module. And I am successful with that by using Conftest for that suite.But now, I would like to distribute tests to multiple CPU/cores using Xdist plugin....when I try to do that each of the process runs conftest and I have multiple instances of the connection. 
Is there a way we can run conftest before starting distribution?
or
Is there a way to achieve this in any different way?

Answer (score 1):

Are you starting your VM like this?

```
# contents of conftest.py
def startup_vm():
    ...

startup_vm()
```

If that's the case, you can use one of the several plugin hooks available instead. Since you want a hook to execute just once per test session, you can use something like this:

```
# contents of conftest.py
def startup_vm():
    ...

def pytest_configure(config):
    startup_vm()

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    shutdown_vm()
```

The full list of plugins is available here:

http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#well-specified-hooks

Comment: Hi, I have a quick question..can I call conftest fixtures in the function called inside pytest.configure?When I could not do it. something like this in conftest.                                              def pytest_configure(config):
    startup_vm(fixture)                                            As I am trying to install VM through a browser/I need to open url. I would like to use opening url as a fixture so that I can reuse it in other test cases